# Wordpress - Create Admin Menu To Specific Page

Tags: php, wordpress, menu

I have the following pages in my WordPress site:
Pole Buildings, Metal Buildings, Log Cabins.

For each page, there is an associated image gallery for product photos.  I am wanting to set up a menu structure **in wp-admin** like this:

```
Pole Buildings
   -> Image Gallery

Metal Buildings
   -> Image Gallery

Log Cabins
   -> Image Gallery
```

I know how to create menu items in the admin but I can't figure out how to add a functioning parent menu for the specific Pages.  Can someone explain how to do this?  This question is specific to a WordPress post type of: Page

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are using same page template for all the three pages, call the menu and display the image gallery with conditions. i.e.,

```
if(page_id==[page_buildings_id]){ //display page buildings image gallery}
elseif(page_id==[metal_buildings_id]){//display metal buildings image gallery}
elseif(page_id==[log_cabin_id]){//display log cabin image gallery}
```

Comment: Thank you for your response.  The question is actually specific to creating a parent menu and a child menu.  The parent menu being a specific page. For example, this would be the menu slug for the Log Cabins Page: (post.php?post=35&action=edit)   I can successfully create a menu with this slug, but when I click on the menu, WP Admin sets the selected menu to: Pages - > All Pages